# Custom checkout paytm integration - checksum provided is invalid error 2005

Tags: javascript, react-native, checksum, paytm

I am using https://github.com/paytm/Paytm_Node_Checksum/blob/master/PaytmChecksum.js for checksum generation. But I am getting the following error when initiate transaction api is invoked:

```
resultInfo: Object { resultStatus: "F", resultCode: "2005", resultMsg: "Checksum provided is invalid" }
​​​​
resultCode: "2005"
​​​​
resultMsg: "Checksum provided is invalid"
​​​​
resultStatus: "F"
```

The params which I am sending are:

```
  params = {
  body: {
    requestType: 'Payment',
    mid: 'myMerchantId',
    orderId: 'OREDRID_98765',
    websiteName: 'WEBSTAGING',
    txnAmount: { value: '1.00', currency: 'INR' },
    userInfo: { custId: 'CUST_001' },
    callbackUrl: 'http://localhost:19006/'
  },
  head: {
    signature: 'QSN7GmO2uFpNevi4aZ4K2qTpcYqlxw89Q9Jf56ZX/h2Scmu0s5EyoTme/OwcfUXY8+v/C+tP4nq65sepQDCZuLPEa6/QRDd26b/4lNLG9fi05ZskqjXqzml1ibZUcbzn'
  }
 }
}
```

And the checksum is generated like this:

```
PaytmChecksum.generateSignature(
    JSON.stringify(params),
    myMerchantKey
);
```

**Help is much appreciated**

Answer (score -1):

I think the below line is causing the error:

```
JSON.stringify(params)
```

You are sending params object as `String` for generating the checksum.
You should actually send body object as `String`.

The above line should be changed to:

```
JSON.stringify(body)
```

Answer (score -1):

Its due to invalid API credentials and parameters. Please check 'mid(merchant id)', 'merchant key', 'websiteName' values.

In your code, you are sending 'signature' in params!!! Here, we are about to generate the Signature, so how you can add it before!!

below is my code:

```
require_once("PaytmChecksum.php");
$orderId = 'ORDERID_'.time();
$paytmParams = array();
    
    $paytmParams["body"] = array("requestType"=>"Payment","mid"=>"<merchant id>","websiteName"=>"WEBSTAGING","orderId"=>$orderId,"callbackUrl"=>"https://answebtechnologies.in/callback","txnAmount"=>array("value"=>"1.00","currency"=>"INR"),"userInfo"
    =>array("custId"=>"CUST_001")); 
    
    $checksum = PaytmChecksum::generateSignature(json_encode($paytmParams["body"], JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES), "<merchant key>");
    
    $paytmParams["head"] = array("signature"=> $checksum); 
    
    $post_data = json_encode($paytmParams, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Answer (score -2):

Please refer to initiate transaction API on Paytm developer's portal for sample request (code snippet)